# LEFT JOIN with list of groups from one table, and flag from another

Tags: mysql, join

First off, sorry if the title is a little off. I'll explain my situation using an example.

I have a `Groups` table like this:

```
id  name
1   admin
2   developer
3   reviewer
4   beta tester
5   contributor
```

I then have a `Permissions` table like so:

```
id   user_id  group_id
1    60       1
2    60       2
3    60       3
```

What I want to do is use a JOIN query to end up with a result like this:

```
(perm.) name   part of group
admin          1
developer      1
reviewer       1
beta tester    0
contributor    0
```

I.e. If there is an entry for a certain user ID which links to a certain group ID, that user is in that group, so a `1` is put in the column. I'm using this to print out a list of checkboxes for an admin page.

My question is simply: how can this be done in MySQL? Obviously a JOIN of some kind, but they confuse the hell out of me. Thanks for any help.

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT g.Name,
       CASE WHEN p.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS part_of_group
    FROM Groups g
        LEFT JOIN Permissions p
            ON g.id = p.group_id
                AND p.user_id  = 60
    ORDER BY part_of_group DESC, g.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    Groups.name,
    Permissions.id is not null
FROM Permissions
RIGHT JOIN Groups ON Permissions.group_id = Groups.id 
WHERE Permissions.user_id = 60
```

The `RIGHT JOIN` means you have a row for each row of the right table (ie `Groups`). If the corresponding row in the left table (ie `Permissions`) don't exists, it is created with `null` for values.

I hope I'm clear :)

The answer with a `LEFT JOIN` proposed by Joe is also perfectly correct, but I think this way is more extensible if you have to add more conditions.

Comment: Thanks very much. Right now, I'm just grabbing the data and not performing any actions on it. I tried this query first, which worked but didn't return _all_ the rows from the `Groups` table. Sorry for not being clear enough. @Joe's answer works well for me. +1 though :-)